# BMI calculator racket with conditional statements error

Tags: racket

I'm trying to create a simple BMI calculator in racket, but I can't find a way to use the conditionals it just don't work. (I'm new in racket)

```
(define (BMI weight height)
  (/ weight (* height height))
  [cond ((and (<= 25)(< 30))(error "Normal"))]
  [cond  ((< 20)(error "Underweight"))])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use [let](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/let.html?q=let#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fletstx-scheme..rkt%29._let%29%29) for creating new local variable.
2. Use only one [cond](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/if.html?q=cond#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fletstx-scheme..rkt%29._cond%29%29) with different clauses.
3. Don't use [error](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/exns.html?q=error#%28def._%28%28quote._%7E23%7E25kernel%29._error%29%29) for output. You can use any other [output function](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Writing.html) (print, write, display...) or just return string from function.

```
(define (BMI weight height)
  (let ((value (/ weight (* height height))))
    (cond ((> 18.5 value) "Underweight")
          ((and (> value 18.5)
                (> 25 value)) "Normal")
          (#true "Obese"))))

(BMI 62 1.85) -> "Underweight"
(BMI 85 1.85) -> "Normal"
(BMI 120 1.85) -> "Obese"
```